# How to force "Recent" links from the taskbar to run as Administrator?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2017 pinned in the taskbar.  I set it to run as an Administrator by right clicking on the icon, then right-clicking on `Visual Studio 2017` entry and selecting `Properties`.

[image]

Then clicking `Advanced` and ticking off the `Run as Administrator` checkbox.

[image]

This works.  I click on Visual Studio icon and it run as an administrator.
However, if I click on any of the links under `Recent`, then Visual Studio doesn't start as an admin.

How do I force Visual Studio 2017 to start as an admin when I select one of the recent links?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are shortcuts. To make a program always run as administrator find the executable. Find the executable, right click it, select the compatibility tab. At the bottom click run as administrator. Now, any shortcut that points to it shouldn't matter. The application is set up to run as administrator.

For visual studio you can run these registry items or close VS, go to the exe, right click, select troubleshoot compatibility, select troubleshoot program, select this program requires additional permissions, then select test program. Click yes to the question do you want to make changes to this computer. VS will eventually start and if it asks you is it running correctly click yes. It may take a couple min to finish.

Or run these in an elevated command prompt.

```
reg.exe Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /d "^ RUNASADMIN"

reg.exe Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\VSLauncher.exe" /d "^ RUNASADMIN" 

reg.exe Add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /d "^ RUNASADMIN" 

reg.exe Add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\VSLauncher.exe" /d "^ RUNASADMIN"
```

Comment: There is no Compatibility tab for this program (devenv.exe).

Comment: Ok. Editing to add for VS